# How to extract a specific class part in element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have elements that have classes like this:

```
class="modal-view arch business"
```

How can I find elements that have the modal- starting word in the class and return the "view" word only or whatever word is in there after modal ?

I tried this already

```
jQuery("*[class^='modal-'],*[class^='modal-'] a").live('click',function(){
var type = jQuery(this).attr('class').split('-')[1];
alert( type );
});
```

It does not work, It shows me view only if the class is modal-view but if there are some other classes it does not work. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

So I am trying to find the part after the modal- but not the other classes. The split code i used works if the class had only **modal-word**

Comment: Are you able to modify the markup at all? This is obviously not the best way to handle things.

Comment: If you can change the markup, I might try something like `<div data-modal-type="view" ... ></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('*[class^=modal-]').live(...);`

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/6zLtq/)

Comment: Look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more selection options. This one is called: Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute starts with selector, then get the className, split on space to get the first class, assuming it's always the first class as in the example, then split the first class on hyphen and pop of the last bit :

```
$(document).on('click', '[class^="modal"]', function() {
    var klass = this.className.split(/\s+/g)[0];
    alert ( klass.split('-').pop() );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VFPk2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a regex match after the split to get the first word after the dash.

```
jQuery("*[class^='modal-'],*[class^='modal-'] a").live('click',function(){
  var type = jQuery(this).attr('class').split('-')[1].match(/\w*/);
  alert( type );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xw87B/

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest (though this is untested, and I'm using `on()` instead of `live()`):

```
$('body').on('click', '[class^="modal-"]', function(){
    var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++){
        if (classes[i].indexOf('modal-') === 0) {
            console.log(classes[i].replace('modal-','');
        }
    }
});
```

I can't, however, think of an 'easy' way that the jQuery library might offer to do this.

It's worth observing, though, that you appear to be solving another problem (the view-state of your application or `modal` dialogue?) in the wrong way which is leading to a complex solution that might not be required.

References:

- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @adeneo: so, I *may* have forgotten to add in a `split()`... (I was originally going to use `classList` and then decided against it, switching to `className`, but forgetting about the array/string difference. Sigh. Thanks for the catch! :) )

Comment: I assumed so; I'm curious about the down-vote though (not concerned as such; I just don't know if I'm leaving something out, overlooking something, or forgot something else...)